# jQuery Mobile: Conditional Image Sizes (Phone/Tablet)

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, tablet

Our jQuery Mobile based site will be used by large screen tablets and phones.

Some of the images we'd like to have smaller when used on a phone.

For example,

```
myImage_large.png
myImage_small.png
```

Is there a way using a data-tag or some other jQuery-mobile method to specify in an img tag that on smaller devices the smaller image should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive images [https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images] looks like it might be pretty close to what you're looking for. It's not necessarily jQuery/mobile specific but it does load different sizes based on the screen resolution.

Comment: Just a heads-up, the link in this answer leads to a page that at the top states: `Note: Project no longer recommended!`

Answer (score 4):

If you use block elements with `background-image`s you can specify in CSS the source of the image, which allows you to create a media query that only loads the proper image. Most mobile browsers support media queries so it's a good idea to start with the hi-res as default and then use a media query to change the `background-image` source to lo-res:

```
/*set source for hi-res images here (default)*/
#image-1 {
    position : relative;
    width    : ...px;
    height   : ...px;
    display  : inline-block;
    background-image : url(/images/this-image-hi.jpg);
} 
@media all and (max-width:480px) {
    /*set source for lo-res images here*/
    #image-1 {
        background-image : url(/images/this-image-lo.jpg);
    }
}
```

Then your image tag would be changed to be something like:

```
<div id="image-1"></div>
```

You could also set all the images source attributes to a blank pixel and then have a JavaScript function change their source on `document.ready`:

```
$(function () {
    if (HI-RES) {
        $('img[data-src-hi]').each(function (index, element) {
            this.src = $(this).attr('data-src-hi');
        });
    } else {
        //output lo-res images
        $('img[data-src-lo]').each(function (index, element) {
            this.src = $(this).attr('data-src-lo');
        });
    }
});
```

This requires your image tags to look like this:

```
<img src="/images/blank-pixel.png" width="xx" height="xx" data-src-hi="/images/this-image-hi.jpg" data-src-lo="/images/this-image-lo.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want it to responds you have to add event of resizing in tablet and smartphones rotating the device will be resize, so you should use resize event to trigger the changes here is an example of what I did:

```
function responsiveImage(hi_res) {
    if (hi_res) {
        $('img[data-src-hi]').each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr('data-src-hi'));
        });
    } else {
        //output lo-res images
        $('img[data-src-lo]').each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr('data-src-lo'));
        });
    }  
}



$(function(){
    var hi_res = false;
    var max_width = 480;

    if($(window).width()>max_width){
        hi_res = true;
    }
    responsiveImage(hi_res);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width()>max_width){
            hi_res = true;
        }else{
            hi_res = false;
        }
        responsiveImage(hi_res);
    });

});
```

use this html

```
<img data-src-hi="/media/img/large_img.png" data-src-lo="/media/img/small_img.png" src="" />
```